# How to create a simple "Expires" workflow to repeat in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I noticed that the "Announcements" web part has the "Expires" feature, but any other links web part I create does not have it. I wanted to add the "Expires" to my custom links web part. So far I got it to delete itself with a simple

If Current Item:Expires is less than Today
   Delete item in Current Item
   then Pause for 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes

But realized it does not repeat itself, only runs when the item is created. How would I get this workflow to run everyday as a background process?

Update: Workflow I'm trying

Step 1
        If Current Item:Expires is less than Today
    Delete item in Current Item

Step 2
        Pause until Current Item:Expires
    then Pause for 1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes
    then Delete item in Current Item

Comment: do you need to delete it multiple times?

Comment: No, just delete item once it reaches expires. So far I found out I have to get a workflow to start at a delayed time (Expires) you create a workflow that starts on "Create", reads the expires date and waits until that time. I tried making the steps myself,

Comment: Updated to show workflow in post. Would something like this work Angelo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this, I think you could just place it where workflow runs on item creation. Since you have a field that would represent when this item should be deleted, you could do this in the workflow:

[image]

if expire date

I'm not sure if the condition is a best practice though, i do this so that it goes to the action every time

in the "this time" value, place in the field "expire"
then it would proceed to deleting the item

What happens here is that the item is left pending until the date you specified in your "expire" field, then it automatically deletes the item.

Comment: I can't seem to get the is not empty to show up. Once I select Current Item:Expires, I can only use equals, not equals, and a value. How did you get the is not empty to show?

Comment: it depends on the field on what items can have the is empty value, not all fields would have that is not empty, but surely for the created by there would always be the is not empty field. I used created by is not empty so that every single time, it goes into that condition and always accepts it as created by will never be empty

Comment: When I use the Current Item:Expires, I'm not able to use is not empty. I just made the Expires value a requirement when submitting the item.